# Capture only the numbers from a string beginning with 's_' and containing a mix of numbers and letters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'd like to extract all the numbers from this string : 's_0a1f2d4e3c10b'. The string must follow this pattern 's_NumberLetterNumberLetter...'
I wrote this regex which matches the whole string :

```
/^q_(?:\d+[a-f])+$/
```

The problem is that I don't know how to capture the numbers only. When I put brackets around the \d+ the regex matches only the last number (10).
Here is the regex with the brackets :

```
^q_(?:(\d+)[a-f])+$
```

Of course I could use `preg_match_all('/\d+/', 's_0a1f2d4e3c10b', $matches)` but I want the string to begin with 's_' and I'd like to use only one regex (if possible).

My desired output from `s_0a1f2d4e3c10b`:

```
array(0, 1, 2, 4, 3, 10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the "continue" metacharacter (`\G`) in your regex to cleanly perform this task in a single `preg_` call.

Matching can ONLY begin if the the substring starts with `s_`.  Then matching can ONLY continue while the alternating number then lowercase letter pattern is upheld.

`\G` actually allows matching from the start of the string or from where the last matched finished.  To deny the feature of matching from the start of the string add a negative lookahead containing a caret symbol (`(?!^)`).

`\K` means restart this fullstring match (or in other words, "forget" any previously matched characters).  This spares the use of capture groups which would otherwise unnecessarily bloat the output array of matches.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/VvagN))

```
$tests = [
    'This string s_0a1f2d4e3c10b is foo.',
    's_1a23b456c789',
    'b_9d9d9d9d9d',
    's_1e2f3a4b'
];

foreach ($tests as $test) {
    var_export(
        preg_match_all(
            '~(?:s_|\G(?!^)[a-z]+)\K\d+~',
            $test,
            $matches
        )
        ? $matches[0]
        : []
    );
    echo "\n---\n";
}
```

Output:

```
['0', '1', '2', '4', '3', '10']
---
['1', '23', '456', '789']
---
[]
---
['1', '2', '3', '4']
---
```

Answer (score 1):

Unsure which result you are after, as you seem to want to keep the s_, but separate numbers (not digits) into values. It's either a string or a list of numbers, not both.

`preg_match_all('/s_\d+|\d+/', 's_0a1f2d4e3c10b', $matches)` will return an array with the first value retaining the `s_` at the beginning.
`preg_match_all('/s_\d+|\d+/', 's_0a1f2d4e3c10b', $matches)` will return an array with the first value being **only** the `s_` and then the subsequent values being the numbers.
Your suggested `preg_match_all('/\d+/', 's_0a1f2d4e3c10b', $matches)` will return only the numbers in an array, and you can add the `s_` prefix if you concatenate them to a string.

Comment: Thank you! I wanted preg_match_all to return an array of numbers only if the string begins with 's_'. I ended up using 2 regex : one for checking the string and the other to extract the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use preg_replace, like this:

```
$count = null;
$returnValue = preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', 's_0a1f2d4e3c10b', -1, $count);
```

this will remove all non-number characters from the string.

`$returnValue` will contain `'0124310'` and `$count` will contain `7` (the number of characters removed)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But I don't see how I could split those digits into numbers, I mean, now 10 can be considered as a 1 and a 0

Comment: @winapiwrapper you did not specify in your initial post that you wanted an array containing the numbers found in the string (which you clarified afterwards in response to comments received), so my suggestion was a way to obtain a string where all non-number characters were removed, as per my understanding of your requirement at the time of your initial post. Anyway, you seem to have resolved your problem now, so everything is good now, and I suggest you accept one of the other answers that helped you the most :-)